# How an autocomplete/lookahead directive can be used in a decoupled way for multiple separate inputs using separate services?

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller, regex-lookarounds

Currently I have three inputs that I need to use autocomplete on that look something like that:

```
<div class="actor-container">
   <input type="text" class="actors"/> 
</div>
<div class="movie-container">
   <input type="text" class="movies"/> 
</div>
<div class="director-container">
   <input type="text" class="directors"/> 
</div>
```

I also have my own autocomplete directive

```
<div my-autocomplete="my-autocomplete" service="serviceName"></div>
```

The autocomplete is getting a serviceName as an input to access different data repositories (search in different pools) using an $injector

What is the best AngularJS practice to connect this directive with the other three inputs? 
I was thinking of putting it in each input like that:

```
<div class="actor-container">
   <input type="text" class="actors" my-autocomplete="my-autocomplete" service="actorService"/> 
</div>
<div class="movie-container">
   <input type="text" class="movies" my-autocomplete="my-autocomplete" service="movieService"/> 
</div>
<div class="director-container">
   <input type="text" class="directors"  my-autocomplete="my-autocomplete" service="directorService"/> 
</div>
```

But is this good practice? Or the directive should be placed "outside" once and then use shared service/broadcast/watch etc to communicate with the each of the three inputs using three separate controllers?

```
<div class="actor-container" ng-controller="addActorCtrl">
   <input type="text" class="actors"/> 
</div>
<div class="movie-container" ng-controller="addMovieCtrl">
   <input type="text" class="movies"/> 
</div>
<div class="director-container" ng-controller="addDirectorCtrl">
   <input type="text" class="directors"/> 
</div>
<div my-autocomplete="my-autocomplete" service="serviceName(how to pass that??)"></div>
```

What should happen is someone should type in each of those fields and the appropriate autocomplete based on a serviceName and what the user input should pop up. Then the user will click on one of the returned entries and this should be added to the right container. I also wonder where the code object.movies.push() (e.g for the movies - when the user clicks a suggested movie) will be placed..

I would really appreciate if you could provide an example with some code because I am fairly new in AngularJS and I think this would be useful for others too :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did and I think it is a good practice:

I have a controller for each of the inputs and I add the directives in each of those:

```
<div ng-controller="addActorCtrl">
     <div suggest-dir="suggest-dir" service="actorService" input-string="{{input1}}" select="addActor(suggestEntry)"></div>
     <input id="actors" name="actors" type="text"  placeholder="" class="input-medium" ng-model="input1"/>
</div>

<div ng-controller="addMovieCtrl">
     <div suggest-dir="suggest-dir" service="movieService" input-string="{{input2}}" select="addMovie(suggestEntry)"></div>
     <input id="actors" name="actors" type="text"  placeholder="" class="input-medium" ng-model="input2"/>
</div>

<div ng-controller="addDirectorCtrl">
     <div suggest-dir="suggest-dir" service="directorService" input-string="{{input3}}" select="addDirector(suggestEntry)"></div>
     <input id="actors" name="actors" type="text"  placeholder="" class="input-medium" ng-model="inpu23"/>
</div>
```

This is my autocomplete directive

```
angular.
module('myApp.suggestModule').
directive('suggestDir',function(){
    // Runs during compile
    return {
        scope: {
            inputString: '@',
            service: '@',
            select: '&'
        },
        controller: [
            '$scope',
            '$injector', 
            function($scope, $injector) {
                this.inputChanged = function(inputString){
                    $injector.get($scope.service).suggest(inputString,
                        function(data){
                            $scope.suggestEntries = data;
                        }
                    );
                };

                this.entryWasClicked = function(suggestEntry){
                    $scope.select({suggestEntry:suggestEntry})
                }

        }],
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'suggestMenu/views/suggest-menu.html',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            scope.$watch('inputString', function(newValue, oldValue) {

                controller.inputChanged(newValue);
            });



        }
    };
})
```

This is my autocomplete entry directive which when it is clicked is calling the `entryWasClicked` from its parent suggestDir. It's parent calls $scope.select but is a & parameter so it is the function that is being passed in `<div suggest-dir select="functionToBeCalled/>`

```
directive('suggestEntryDir',function(){
        // Runs during compile
        return {
            require: '^suggestDir',
            restrict: 'A',
            templateUrl: 'suggestMenu/views/suggest-entry.html',

            link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                var suggestEntry = scope.$eval(attrs.suggestEntry);

                element.bind('click', function(e){
                    scope.$apply(function(){ controller.entryWasClicked(suggestEntry)})
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

This is one of the wrapper controllers (that I used for each of the inputs) so everything is decoupled:

```
controller('addActorCtrl',[
    '$scope',
    function($scope){

      var obj= $scope.obj;

        $scope.addActor= function (actor){
                if(!obj.actors){
                    obj.actors = [];
                }
                obj.actors.push(actors);   
            };
    }]);
```

This is one of the services (the actorService). Services bring data from the database and behave as repositories:

```
angular.
    module('myApp.actorModule').
    constant('restAPI','http://localhost/project/').
    factory('actorService',['$http','restAPI',function($http,restAPI){
        return {
            latest: function (callback){
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '',
                    cache: true
                }).success(callback);
            },

            find: function(id, callback){
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: restAPI+'actor/'+id,
                    cache: true
                }).success(callback);
            },

            suggest: function(stringInput,callback){
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: restAPI+'actor/suggest/'+stringInput,
                    cache: true
                }).success(callback);
            },

            update: function(id,actor, callback){
                $http({
                    method: 'PUT',
                    url: restAPI+'actor/'+id,
                    data: actor
                }).success(callback);
            }
        }
    }])
```

Finally this is the template for my suggestion directive:

```
<div id="suggestions" ng-show="suggestEntries.length>0 && inputString.length>0">
<div class="scrollbar"><div class="track"><div class="thumb"><div class="end"></div></div></div></div>
<div class="viewport">
    <div id="suggestions-list" class="overview">
        <div class="types" ng-repeat="suggestEntry in suggestEntries">
            <div suggest-entry-dir="suggest-entry-dir" suggest-entry="suggestEntry"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="close" style="width:10px; cursor: pointer; height:10px; background-color:#aaaaff; position:absolute; top: 4px; right: 4px;"></div>
</div>
```

and this is for the suggestEntry

```
<div class="suggest-entry  suggest-{{suggestEntry.label}}">
    {{suggestEntry.textIndexed}}

</div>
```